# GetCell method ignores changed values

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I have a **UITableView** set up with **GetCell**, **RowsInSection**, and other methods required for my **UITableView**. Here is my code:

```
using UIKit;
...
    
namespace ...
{
    public partial class (className) : UIViewController, IUITextFieldDelegate, IUITableViewDataSource, IUITableViewDelegate

    bool test = false;

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        table.ReloadData();
        table.DataSource = this;
        table.Delegate = this;

        test = true;
    }

    ...

    public nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
    {
        return 2;
    }

    public UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell("cell") as Cell;

        bool selected = test;

        cell.Setup(selected);
        return cell;
    }

}
```

What I attempt to do is checking a changed value of a variable while setting up the cell in **GetCell**. However, it seems that the **GetCell** method ignores the changed value of the variable **test**, so my question is how do I access the variable after the change in **ViewDidLoad**.

Comment: You are modifying `test` after you have called `reloadData` So when `Getcell` is called `test` is `false` Unless you reload the tableview again or something else causes some cells to be redrawn (new cells scrolling into view, for example) 'GetCell` won't be called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Call `table.ReloadData();` after modifying `test` , because [reloadData](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614862-reloaddata?language=objc) is used to trigger all the methods in the delegate including `GetCell` .

   ```
   table.DataSource = this;
   table.Delegate = this;
   test = true;
   table.ReloadData();
   ```
2. Your code is not for cell reuse , pls refer to the correct way [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/user-interface/controls/tables/populating-a-table-with-data#cell-reuse) .

   ```
    //register
    table.RegisterClassForCellReuse (typeof(Cell), "cell");


    public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        //cell reuse 
        var cell = (Cell) tableView.DequeueReusableCell ("cell", indexPath);
        if (cell == null)  cell = new Cell("cell");

        bool selected = test;

        cell.Setup(selected);
        return cell;
    }
   ```